# Proving that Fubini metric is well-defined

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-space, kahler-manifolds

Let
$$\pi:S^{2n+1}\to S^{2n+1}/S^1=\mathbb{P}^n\mathbb{C}$$
be the Hopf fibration. I already know that $d_z\pi$ is a vector space isomorphism for every $z\in S^{2n+1}$ (when restricted to the orthogonal space to the orbit). We'd like to define a riemannian structure on $\mathbb{P}^n\mathbb{C}$ by push-forwarding the riemannian structure of $S^{2n+1}$ on each tangent space through $d_z \pi$. Basically we want to define the **Fubini metric** as:

$$\mathsf{fub}_{[z]}(u,v):=\mathsf{sph}_z((d_z\pi)^{-1}(u),(d_z\pi)^{-1}(v)),$$

where $\mathsf{sph}$ is the standard spheric metric. The only problem with this definition is that it may depend on the choice of the representative $z$ of the equivalence class $[z]$. So let $e^{i\theta}z$ be a new representative:

$$\mathsf{sph}_{e^{i\theta}z}((d_{e^{i\theta}z}\pi)^{-1}(u),(d_{e^{i\theta}z}\pi)^{-1}(v))=\langle (d_{e^{i\theta}z}\pi)^{-1}(u), d_{e^{i\theta}z}\pi)^{-1}(v) \rangle$$

where $\langle -,- \rangle$ is the standard euclidean inner product on $\mathbb{C}^{n}\cong \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (the fixed isomorphism is $(x_1+iy_1,...,x_n+iy_n)\to (x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n)$). My problems would be over if I had an euclidean isometry $I:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}^n$ such that:

$$(d_{e^{i\theta}z}\pi)^{-1}=I\circ (d_z\pi)^{-1}$$

so basically I'd like to prove that:

$$(d_{e^{i\theta}z}\pi)^{-1}\circ (d_z\pi)$$

is an euclidean isometry. Is there an elegant way of doing this without dwelving too much into coordinates? Or in alternative, is there a better approach?

Comment: (not addressing your question, but) wouldn't "pushing-forward" be more accurate that "push-forwarding"?

Comment: @Didier You are obviously right, this is just a linguistic mismatch. In Italian we often import from English some mathematical terminology like "pull-back" and then we colloquially turn it into a verb by putting the conjugation suffix. So I basically retranslated (too literally!) an Italian mathematical slang term (derived from an English mathematical term) into English

Comment: I guess it's the same in French: I think I already said something like "push-forward*er*" or "pull-back*er*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\iota\colon S^{2n+1} \to \Bbb C^{n+1}$ be the inclusion map.
Let $f_{\lambda}\colon \Bbb C^{n+1} \to \Bbb C^{n+1}$ and $\bar{f}_{\lambda}\colon S^{2n+1}\to S^{2n+1}$ both be the multiplication by $\lambda \in \Bbb S^1$ (but not on the same space).
Both are diffeomorphisms.
One readily checks that the following commutative diagram holds
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S^{2n+1} @>{\iota}>> \Bbb C^{n+1}\\
@V{\bar{f}_{\lambda}}VV @VV{f_{\lambda}}V \\
S^{2n+1} @>{\iota}>> \Bbb C^{n+1}
\end{CD}$$
that is, that $\iota\circ \bar{f}_{\lambda} = f_{\lambda}\circ \iota$.

Let $g$ be the natural metric on $\Bbb C^{n+1}$.
It is clear that $f_{\lambda}$ is an isometry, so that $f_{\lambda}^*g = g$.
Let $h=\iota^*g$ be the induced metric on the sphere.
Then
$$
\bar{f}_{\lambda}^* h = \bar{f}_{\lambda}^*\iota^*g = (\iota\circ \bar{f}_{\lambda})^*g= (f_{\lambda}\circ \iota)^*g = \iota^* f_{\lambda}^*g = \iota^*g = h,
$$
that is, $\bar{f}_{\lambda}$ is an isometry for $h$.

Comment: @Kandinskij I rewrote my answer to be fully rigorous.

Comment: Thank you very much :)